# Retrieve only numbers using sql query

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to only select numeric data from mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756736/how-to-only-select-numeric-data-from-mysql)

Hi,

I want to select all values that are only numbers from the db, using

SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name = '0..9'

How do I get only numbers.

Thanks Jean

Comment: @gumbo the soln provided by cdhowie works, its simple, compared to the link above, I find no reason for this question to be closed, please open it

Comment: I did not close the question because there were no correct answers. I closed the question because it is a duplicate. In essence both questions ask how to identify numeric values.

Comment: @gumbo though the questions appear the same, the answers are quite different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE column_name REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'
```

Comment: I removed the +$, it worked and if it is for numbers a-z, its not working when replaced.

Comment: im sorry alphabets then?

Comment: You are not making any sense at all.  I thought you wanted to select only values that consistent entirely of numeric data?

Comment: Yes true, now if I want to select only alphabets a-z

Comment: Then change `0-9` in the regexp to `a-z`.  Or `a-zA-Z` if you want to allow capital letters too.

Comment: thanks it worked....... please vote to reopen this question...

Comment: I can't cast a reopen vote, but it doesn't really appear to matter too much... people can still find it, and accepting an answer works.  New answers just can't be added.

Answer (score 0):

There is another thread similar to this that may help:

[How to only select numeric data from mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756736/how-to-only-select-numeric-data-from-mysql)