# SQL SELECT rows with numbers on column?

Tags: mysql

**Possible Duplicate: [How to only select numeric data from mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756736/how-to-only-select-numeric-data-from-mysql)**

I have a column which actually houses strings (type varchar) is there a way to select rows that only hold numbers in them?

E.G:

```
COLUMN1 COLUMN2 COLUMN3
1234    dassa   dasasfa
aaaa    fdsa    dsfa 
4dsf4   dfssa   aaddss
```

The query should return

```
1234    dassa   dasasfa
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to only select numeric data from mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756736/how-to-only-select-numeric-data-from-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by this query in mysql

```
select * from st where COLUMN1 REGEXP '^[0-9]+$';
```

the result will be

```
COLUMN1     COLUMN2     COLUMN3
1234        dassa       dasasfa
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `COLUMN1` REGEXP '^[[:digit:]]+$'
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp

Comment: Aww, 12 seconds ahead of me. That's what I get for using linebreaks.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression matching with `REGEXP()`

```
SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3
FROM tbl
WHERE COLUMN1 REGEXP '^[0-9]+$';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
where column1 regexp '^[[:digit:]]+$'
```

I think should do it.

Another idea:

```
where case(round(column,0) as char) = column1
```