# How can I delete MySQL records which have a field which is not numeric?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Due to a data corruption, we have a database field (Mysql 5) which has been populated with text. Its a custom field in the ExpressionEngine CMS and was not set as numeric only. I need to delete only those records for which this field has been incorrectly populated. It contains a URL instead of an ID e.g. 10937.

I need to run a query / stored procedure which will find only those records which have been incorrectly populated i.e do not contain a numeric ID and delete those records, plus linked records in another table.

I would welcome advice on the best way to do this. I could do it from PHP but was hoping to do it in a stored procedure as this would be a useful skill to learn. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756736/how-to-only-select-numeric-data-from-mysql) has details of a function which can test if a field is numeric. But I actually need the opposite.

The query I have which will select the records in question is:

```
SELECT field_id_58 as 'release_id' , ewt.entry_id FROM exp_weblog_data ewd
LEFT JOIN exp_weblog_titles ewt ON ewt.`entry_id` = ewd.`entry_id`
WHERE ewt.weblog_id = 15
```

This returns all the cms entry_ids I am dealing with, including the ones I want to delete. The field with the incorrect data is field_id_58. The fact that this field has been incorrectly populated means we now have duplicate records in tables ewt and ewd.

Here's what I have so far:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `proc_DEL_DUPLICATE_PR`
BEGIN
    DECLARE empty INT;
    DECLARE result ??? # not sure what data type this should be
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT field_id_58 as 'release_id' , ewt.entry_id FROM exp_weblog_data ewd
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN exp_weblog_titles ewt ON ewt.`entry_id` = ewd.`entry_id`
                            WHERE ewt.weblog_id = 15;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET empty=1;
    OPEN cur1;
    SET empty =0;
    WHILE empty = 0 DO
        FETCH cur1 INTO result;
        #if the release_id in the result row contains a URL string then delete rows for tables ewt, ewd for that entry_id
        END IF;
    END WHILE;

    CLOSE cur1;

END //
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions to find non-numeric fields. The following query will find any rows for which the specified column's value is non-numeric:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name REGEXP '[^0-9].+'
```

Any rows which have a purely numeric value will not be returned. If your *DELETE* statement uses the same *WHERE* clause, that should do it.

To delete the rows that contain non-numeric column values, try this query:

```
DELETE FROM exp_weblog_titles ewt 
    INNER JOIN exp_weblog_data ewd ON
        ewt.`entry_id` = ewd.`entry_id` 
    WHERE ewt.weblog_id = 15 AND ewd.field_id_58 REGEXP '[^0-9].+';

DELETE FROM exp_weblog_data ewd WHERE ewd.field_id_58 REGEXP '[^0-9].+';
```

It first deletes all of the relevant rows from the child table, then deletes the parent table rows. Use at your own risk, obviously.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea how I would access the entry_id and release_id values in my 'result' variable and what data type I should set that to?

Comment: Updated to include deletion advice. I'm not sure what you mean by your last sentence, are you looking to preserve some data?

Comment: Thanks again. I was referring to the lines creating a result variable in the stored procedure. I had assumed that 'FETCH cur1 INTO result;' would contain the entry_id and release_id per row.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL actually needed to look like this:

```
DELETE FROM ewt
USING exp_weblog_titles AS ewt
INNER JOIN exp_weblog_data ewd ON ewt.entry_id = ewd.entry_id
WHERE ewt.weblog_id = 15 
AND ewd.field_id_58 REGEXP '[^0-9].+';

DELETE FROM exp_weblog_data ewd WHERE ewd.field_id_58 REGEXP '[^0-9].+';
```