# Extract numbers in a body of text in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, return-value

Suppose I have a column that has text with numbers. For example,

Row 1: I have 3 apples. 
 
Row 2: In y2009, my bill was 32 dollars. 
Row 3: 22 years old.

I want to create a column as follows:

Row 1: 3 
Row 2: 32 
 
Row 3: 22

Note that I do not want to accidentally extract 2009 from y2009. I just want 32. 
I tried the following, but it only extracts rows where the numbers come first.

```
SELECT @num := CONVERT(`col1`, SIGNED) AS num_part FROM my_table;
```

Comment: My guess is if this is too complicated for a MySQL query, I can do it in Python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756736/how-to-only-select-numeric-data-from-mysql