# Sorting table using the numbers in my data

Tags: html, mysql, database

I have this data in my table and I want to sort it using the numbers in the data.

Data unsorted

```
5 team team team team
team team team 2 team
team team team team 4
team 1 team team team
team team 3 team team
```

Data Sorted

```
team 1 team team team
team team team 2 team
team team 3 team team
team team team team 4
5 team team team team
```

Comment: Do you know that the values 1 through 5 are contained in the strings. If so then just use a CASE statement

Comment: how to use a case statement? @Strawberry

Comment: or have a good data model. Need help with that ?

Comment: how about this then, type `show create table myTableName`, share that, let us get a good count column in there for the order by

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet might be a brute force approach:

```
order by (case when col like '%1%' then 1
               when col like '%2%' then 2
               . . .
          end)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION IsNumeric (val varchar(255)) RETURNS tinyint 
 RETURN val REGEXP '^(-|\\+){0,1}([0-9]+\\.[0-9]*|[0-9]*\\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)$';

CREATE FUNCTION GetNumericOnly (val VARCHAR(255)) 
 RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
BEGIN
 DECLARE idx INT DEFAULT 0;
 IF ISNULL(val) THEN RETURN NULL; END IF;

 IF LENGTH(val) = 0 THEN RETURN ""; END IF;

 SET idx = LENGTH(val);
  WHILE idx > 0 DO
  IF IsNumeric(SUBSTRING(val,idx,1)) = 0 THEN
   SET val = REPLACE(val,SUBSTRING(val,idx,1),"");
   SET idx = LENGTH(val)+1;
  END IF;
  SET idx = idx - 1;
  END WHILE;
  RETURN val;
 END;
```

Then use it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mixedvalues
ORDER BY GetNumericOnly(value)
```

Reference: [How to only select numeric data from mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756736/how-to-only-select-numeric-data-from-mysql)

SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6fb95/2/0